# VC++ Installs - Error 1603, "error 997.overlapped i/o operation is in progress"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, installation, failed-installation

A large proportion of programs I try to install (all adobe programs, Unity, V++ Redistributables, and more) don't install. I have a new PC with a fresh new version of windows 10. All of these programs say something related to V++ Redistributable and error code 1603 (photoshop CC, for example, shows errors under "ERROR: Third party payload installer vcredist_x64.exe failed with exit code: 1603" and "ERROR: Third party payload installer vcredist_x86.exe failed with exit code: 1603". I cannot install VC++ from any exe or msi.

For the VC++ 2008 Redistributable, I get this message pop up: https://gyazo.com/e23fbb88609b122e3dd9639ea8c71b24
"error 997.overlapped i/o operation is in progress"

If I look at the logs in other VC++ installs, sure enough error 997 comes up. When I search this error up, a common suggestion is to reinstall security updates, but I only have one which isn't on the list of ones I should reinstall (even if I do it does nothing). Another suggestion is to do something in the registry, but the "installation" folder it points to isn't there, and I have no idea what I'm doing in the registry and will probably end up breaking my windows if I try to make my own registry folder.

Could someone please help me? This is really slowing down my work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @Takarii it's about programming tools as im using it to install unity, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About “error 997.overlapped i/o operation is in progress”, you can check this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2014/10/27/error-997-overlapped-io-operation-is-in-progress-kb2918614-breaks-windows-installer-service/

1. Renaming C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18 to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18_old
2. Confirm the administrator is the ownership and full control on the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18 folder, if not, took ownership and re-applied permissions as full control on this.
3. If you do not have this registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsInstaller, you can back up the registry table and create it and add DWORD "SecureRepairPolicy with value of 1.
4. Windows update is up-to-date, after that, search for KB2918614/ KB3072630/KB3000988/KB3008627 and once it is found, remove it and restart the computer.

Comment: How do #1 and #2 make sense? You've just renamed the folder to .old and now you want to check permissions on the original name which no longer exists? This is too confusing.